# Can we flag a user as a potential bot?

Tags: discussion, flags, robots

I ran into a "user" while doing a review task on SO. [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1558187/user1558187) has made [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785679/can-mvc-custom-error-pages-retain-route-values/15952749#15952749) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785679/can-mvc-custom-error-pages-retain-route-values/15953097#15953097) on the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785679/can-mvc-custom-error-pages-retain-route-values), as far as I can tell these are not close to answers they are just html dumps.

I suspect this user to be a bot of some sort and I was wondering if there is a way I could flag a user for some sort of review... Or is just calling them out on Meta enough? I already flagged the "answers" and left a comment. Anything else we should do in this case?

**EDIT**: the Answers were deleted so they're 10K only now, sorry.

Comment: How about the `other` option in the moderator attention flag box?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - that flags a post (Q or A or comment), I'm talking about flagging a *user*. I think this "user" is not a person so why just delete the posts instead of get to the source of the problem

Comment: You still flag the posts. Moderators are humans, they'll usually figure out that the *user* needs investigating.. Flagging for mod attention is for more than just having a post deleted.

Comment: @Josh agreed, `Is it possible to flag a user rather than just individual posts` is a dup, sorry I missed that when posting.

Comment: No need to apologize, @Mike.

Answer (score 8):

You can't flag users directly, but you can just flag any of their posts and explain to the moderators why they should investigate this user.

Flagging is preferred over meta for such issues as it is less noisy and user-specific meta posts can get rather unconstructive. Publicly calling out specific users is discouraged.

Comment: OK, this `calling out specific users is discouraged` with Martijn's comment pretty much answers my question. "Flag the posts and nature will take its course on the user"

Comment: @Mike I meant specifically calling them out in public, in a flag it is a good idea to mention if you noticed problems with this user beyond the single post you flagged.

Comment: Yes, I know what you meant, and that is how I handled the flagging of the answers from the user that were suspect. I was saying your answer tells me posting suspected bot-users on Meta is not proper, and I thank you for that clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you flag with `it needs ♦ moderator attention`, then a diamond moderator will look into it for you. Use `other` and indicate your reasoning and justifications.

Though, I'm not sure if two answers constitutes a bot.

Edit: Looking into this user, I have to agree, those edits are pretty suspicious. It looks like attempted advertising of some sort, or just random edits. I'd probably flag it.

Comment: Given the particular suggested edits by that user, something fishy is going on. Bot-like at least.

Comment: Even if a flag isn't likely to be really conclusive, if you see something _really_ strange like that, it's better to flag as other and explain. Moderators will generally validate that specific type of flag if they can see why you raised an eyebrow or three (did I mention strange?)

Comment: @Bart I just looked into the user's activity, and I agree with you. It's rather strange. So yeah, flag is a good option.

Comment: Based on the sequence of edits, it looks more like someone is trying to write a bot to auto-edit stackoverflow posts.

Comment: On the bright side, no one approved any of the edits